# Evolution sending Email Settings

Tags: evolution, smtp

Can receive Comcast mail with evolution but cannot send.

The SMTP settings record more digits when clicking the Server Configuration apply key.

Sending (smtp@comcast.net:tenz222)  port587

After clicking apply, receive a "Error while sending message" host lookup failed etc

When rechecking,the sever settings are, (smpt@comcast.net%253atenz222)

Attempted this process many times with same result.

Now need to be proactive and ask for help.

Will phone for help anywhere, anytime in USA.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all we need to know both your incoming and outgoing mail servers, which may be different in certain cases.

Focusing on your only issue to send email, let's see how my "Sending Email" tab in the "Account Editor" window looks like, as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, my "Server configuration" reads the outgoing server's name plus the port after the two points symbol.

Additionally, Port 587 may require authentication based on your email's name and not just your nick and make sure you don't need to use a encrypted secure connection.

Give this a try and please inform on your outgoing server's name in order to change this answer if needed. Usually, doing what I mentioned here fixes that issue.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The day before yesterday (March 21, 2013), evolution both sent and received mail from att.net without a hitch.  Yesterday it failed to send.  I found this thread and a few others looking for an answer, even tried Thunderbird (which did work).  My eventual solution was to **turn on SSL encryption for sending.** It was already on for receiving.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up a IMAP/SMTP account in Evolution **without** TLS encryption.
For receiving E-Mails (IMAP) worked fine on the standard port `143` with `No encryption`. However for sending (SMTP) I had to choose port `465` and *Encryption method* `TLS on a dedicated port` to work properly; the standard `25` port without encryption did not work. Even though the administrator of the E-Mail server tells me that the E-Mails are sent without encryption. So it must be kind of a bug there.